# Best way to assign value on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

What is the correct way to identify max value in subgroup and assign each row value based on whether it is max or not?
Here is an example df:

```
group            subgroup
  A                 1
  B                 1
  A                 2
  A                 3
  A                 4
  B                 2
  C                 2
  C                 1
```

The rules are:

```
if subgroup = max then result = 1
else subgroup = 2
```

Result will be:

```
group            subgroup      result
  A                 1            2
  B                 1            2
  A                 2            2
  A                 3            2
  A                 4            1
  B                 2            1
  C                 2            1
  C                 1            2
```

I do it this way now:

```
df['subgroup_max'] = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].nunique()
df3['result'] = 2
df3.loc[df3['result'] == df3['subgroup_max'],'result'] = 1
```

Doesn't seem to be very efficient. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indexes of `max` values per group:

```
df['result'] = 2
idx = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].idxmax()
df.loc[idx, 'result'] = 1
print (df)
  group  subgroup  result
0     A         1       2
1     B         1       2
2     A         2       2
3     A         3       2
4     A         4       1
5     B         2       1
6     C         2       1
7     C         1       2
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
idx = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].idxmax()
df['result'] = np.where(df.index.isin(idx), 1, 2)
print (df)
  group  subgroup  result
0     A         1       2
1     B         1       2
2     A         2       2
3     A         3       2
4     A         4       1
5     B         2       1
6     C         2       1
7     C         1       2
```

---

```
idx = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].idxmax()
df['result'] = (~df.index.isin(idx)).astype(int) + 1
print (df)
  group  subgroup  result
0     A         1       2
1     B         1       2
2     A         2       2
3     A         3       2
4     A         4       1
5     B         2       1
6     C         2       1
7     C         1       2
```

But if there is multiple max values per group and need assign value to all maxes use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
print (df)
  group  subgroup
0     A         4
1     B         1
2     A         2
3     A         3
4     A         4
5     B         2
6     C         2
7     C         1

mask = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].apply(lambda x: x == x.max())
df['result'] = np.where(mask, 1, 2)
print (df)
  group  subgroup  result
0     A         4       1
1     B         1       2
2     A         2       2
3     A         3       2
4     A         4       1
5     B         2       1
6     C         2       1
7     C         1       2
```

Comment: thanks jezrael! Yes there are multiple max values. Do you know if this solution is faster than the one i used in question?

Comment: I think yes. I dont create helper column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda function also,it gives you the ability to specify more conditions.

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','B','A','A','A','B','C','C'],'subgroup':[1,1,2,3,4,2,2,1]})

 group  subgroup
0     A         1
1     B         1
2     A         2
3     A         3
4     A         4
5     B         2
6     C         2
7     C         1



df['results']=df['subgroup'].apply( lambda x:1 if df['subgroup'].max()==x else 2)



group  subgroup  results
0     A         1        2
1     B         1        2
2     A         2        2
3     A         3        2
4     A         4        1
5     B         2        2
6     C         2        2
7     C         1        2
```